# Making an app for iphone without putting it to app store

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I have developer account for ios. And I'd like to send my app to some people to look and test it. Is there a way to export my app and send it without adding it to app store? (it's not finished quite yet, and i need to show results for people far away..)

Thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you have any customers to test your app before sending to App-Store , you’re better off distributing with an **.ipa** file using your  developer account .

You can send the .ipa through any way to customers because clients can easily install the .ipa files through **iTunes**.

You can use multiple platforms to deploy/install your app in customers device. Example **TestFlight, Appaloosa store** etc..

Answer (score 1):

You need to create what's called an *ad-hoc* distribution of your app.

Answer (score 0):

Use TestFlight, it's the best way.
https://testflightapp.com/